# Concatenate multiple files with same header

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have multiple files with the same header and different vectors below that. I need to concatenate all of them but I want only the header of first file to be concatenated and I don't want other headers to be concatenated since they are all same.

for example:
file1.txt

```
<header>INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer>
<header>INFO=<ID=DP4,Number=4,Type=Integer>
A
B 
C
```

file2.txt

```
<header>INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer>
<header>INFO=<ID=DP4,Number=4,Type=Integer>
D
E 
F
```

I need the output to be

```
<header>INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer>
<header>INFO=<ID=DP4,Number=4,Type=Integer>
A
B
C
D
E 
F
```

I could write a script in R but I need it in shell?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you know how to do it in R, then by all means do it in R. With classical unix tools, this is most naturally done in awk.

```
awk '
    FNR==1 && NR!=1 { while (/^<header>/) getline; }
    1 {print}
' file*.txt >all.txt
```

The first line of the awk script matches the first line of a file (`FNR==1`) except if it's also the first line across all files (`NR==1`). When these conditions are met, the expression `while (/^<header>/) getline;` is executed, which causes awk to keep reading another line (skipping the current one) as long as the current one matches the regexp `^<header>`. The second line of the awk script prints everything except for the lines that were previously skipped.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. Each of my files are in GBs. R won't be efficient do this. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Jana Are there lines that look like headers but aren't at the top of the file? If not, the fastest way is to use `grep` (like in [sputnik's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60578)).

Comment: No the header lines are similar to all files and they are just at the top of each file. Yeah grep was faster. Thanks both of you

Comment: @Jana By the way, if all your files have the same number of header lines, here's another way (which I expect to be even faster): `head -n 10 file1.txt >output.txt && tail -q -n +11 file*.txt >>output.txt` (if you have 10 header lines). Also, if your files have numbers in their names, beware that `file9.txt` is sorted between `file89.txt` and `file90.txt`. If your files have numbers like `file001.txt`, …, `files009.txt`, `files010.txt`, …, then `files*.txt` will list them in the right order.

Comment: A better solution (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890695/310441) that doesn't require regex matching:  `awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' *.csv`

Comment: @Owen The additional code in my answer is necessary because there's a multiline header.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', your solution worked well! But I am a little greedy and would like to find a way to make the code more "general-purpose". For now, I have to first figure out what the header line is. Is there a way to save this step?

Comment: @user3768495 I don't understand the question. What defines a header line depends on the format of the data.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', you are exactly right! And what I meant to say is, is it possible to have a script that works every time, no matter what the actual header line is in the data file?

Comment: @user3768495 How is it supposed to recognize what is a header line? In this question, a header line starts with `<header>`. Without specifying this, there's no way to know what is the last header line and what is the first data line.

Answer (score 68):

Another solution, similar to "`cat+grep`" from above, using `head` and GNU `tail` or compatible:

1. Write the header of the first file into the output:

   ```
   head -n 2 file1.txt > all.txt
   ```

   -- `head -n 2` gets 2 first lines of the file.
2. Add the content of all the files:

   ```
   tail -n +3 -q file*.txt >> all.txt
   ```

   -- `-n +3` makes `tail` print lines from 3rd to the end; GNU `tail` can take more than one filename as argument (as a common extension over the standard), and with `-q` (also a GNU extension, also supported on FreeBSD and NetBSD) tells it  not to print the header with the file name (read `man`),
   `>>` adds to the file, not overwrites it as `>`.

And sure you can put both commands in one line:

```
head -n 2 file1.txt > all.txt; tail -n +3 -q file*.txt >> all.txt
```

or instead of `;` put `&&` between them for success check.

Note that shell glob expansions are sorted lexically by default. That means that while `file1.txt` to `file9.txt` will be sorted numerically, `file10.txt` will sort in between `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` (or possibly even before `file1.txt` depending on the locale). If using `zsh`, use `file*.txt(n)` for a numerical sort.

Comment: I suggest to further simply it to:
`(head -2 file1.txt ; tail -n +3 -q file*.txt ) > all.txt`
or
`(head -2 file1.txt && tail -n +3 -q file*.txt ) > all.txt`

Answer (score 5):

Try doing this :

```
$ cat file1.txt; grep -v "^<header" file2.txt
<header>INFO=<ID=DP,Number=1,Type=Integer>
<header>INFO=<ID=DP4,Number=4,Type=Integer>
A
B 
C
D
E 
F
```

## NOTE

- the `-v` flag means to invert the match of [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)
- `^` in [REGEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), means *beginning of the string*
- if you have a bunch of files, you can do

:

```
array=( files*.txt )
{ cat ${array[@]:0:1}; grep -v "^<header" ${array[@]:1}; } > new_file.txt
```

It's a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) array slicing technique.

Comment: Thanks sputnick, But I have ~30 files(file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt..filen.txt) to be concatenated. Should I type every file name or is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: See my edited post with slicing technique

Comment: This removes `<header>` lines anywhere in the files, not just at the beginning. This may not be an issue here, depending on the data.

Comment: Simpler: `grep '^<header>' file1.txt >output.txt && grep -v '^<header>' file*.txt >>output.txt`

Comment: @Gilles: I noticed your answer after a long time but it was very useful

Comment: this is great, but when I have more than two files the file name is prepended to the line being added, which is not ideal ... :-/ but can easily be fixed by using the -h flag on grep

Answer (score 1):

The `tail` command (on GNU, at least) has an option to skip a given number of initial lines.  To print from the second line onward, i.e. skip a one-line header, do: `tail -n+2 myfile`

So, to keep the two-line header of the first file but not the second, in Bash:

```
cat file1.txt <(tail -n+3 file2.txt) > combined.txt
```

Or, for many files:

```
head -n1 file1.txt > combined.txt
for fname in *.txt
do
    tail -n+3 $fname >> combined.txt
done
```

If a certain string is known to be present in all header lines but never in the rest of the input files, `grep -v` is a simpler approach, as sputnik showed.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter (not necessarily faster) with `sed`:

```
sed -e '3,${/^<header>/d' -e '}' file*.txt > all.txt
```

This will delete all lines beginning with `<header>...` starting from line 3, so the first header is preserved and the other headers are removed. If there's a different number of lines in the header adjust the command accordingly (e.g. for 6-line header use `7` instead of `3`).
If the number of lines in the header is unknown you could try like this:

```
sed '1{
: again
n
/^<header>/b again
}
/^<header>/d
' file*.txt > all.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

> array=( *.txt );head -1 ${array[0]} > all.txt; tail -n +2 -q
>   ${array[@]:0} >> all.txt

Assuming you are using a folder with .txt files with the same header that need to be combined/concatenated , this code would combine the txt files all into **all.txt** with just one header.  the first line (lines separated by semicolons) gathers all the text files to concatenate, the second lines outputs the header from the first txt file into **all.txt**, and the last line concatenates all the text files gathered without the header (by starting the concatenation from row 2 onwards) and appends it to **all.txt**.

Comment: a tiny bit of explanation would go a long way towards helping future users

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lazy script to help with this. Not totally robust, but good enough.

```
function concat_with_header() {
  # Quoted suffix to pattern match for concatenation (e.g. '*.csv')
  local suffix="${1}"
  # Name of the output file
  local output="${2:-combined.out}"
  # Number of lines to use for the header
  local header_length="${3:-1}"
  # Grab the header from the first file
  local header=`echo -e "$(ls -b *$suffix | head -n$header_length)"`
  head -1 $header_file > $output; tail -n +"`expr $header_length + 1`" -q *$suffix >> $output
}
```

Comment: the last two lines seem to have errors: "header" variable is not used anywhere, the `head` command options appear to be switched (you want the first filename - not the $header_length first few files but the first $header_length lines of the $header_file - not necessarily the first line. "header_file" variable is not defined anywhere, quoting variables (last line of the function) is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If all your files have the same number of header lines (2 in your case), another very simple solution for lazy people like me is this:

```
head -2 file1.txt > all.txt
awk 'FNR>2{print}' file*.txt >> all.txt
```

Very similar to using `head` + `tail` as in the first answer:

1. First you write the header
2. Then you append all other files without headers