# Combining files in a directory by header and omitting shared content

Tags: cat, merge

so I have found a question on here that is the opposite of what I would like to do here: [Concatenate multiple files with same header](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60577/concatenate-multiple-files-with-same-header?rq=1).

I am trying to merge or concatenate 2 files,within a directory within hundred of files that have a counterpart file with the same substring, into one file based on the '>' character in the header. There are thousands of headers within the each file and as opposed to the question asked in the link I attached, the contents other than the header are the same so I don't want to change anything but every line that begins with '>'.

Essentially I would like to combine file1 to file2 by the shared character '>' and to leave the contents of file 1 in order.

```
File1
> MGBNCNOSNC_142
9u2o4840204a9
> MGBNCNOSNC_143
AOISCJNWDCSNDCCW
> MGBNCNOSNC_144
AOISCJ40204DZZW
```

---

```
File2
>King_Henry
>Queen_jerry
>Jack_jill
```

---

```
Output
> MGBNCNOSCNC_142 > King_henry
9u2o4840204a9
> MGBNCNOSCNC_143 > Queen_jerry
AOISCJNWDC
> MGBNCNOSNC_144 > Jack_jill
gefSCJ40204DZZW
```

Thanks for any help and let me know if I can be any clearer!

Comment: It might be clearer if you re-worked the formating - you might want to use code formating (indent by 4 spaces) in place of block quotes. Also clarify whether the lines begin with `>` (as indicated in your text) or with `'>` (as apparently shown in your sample input). Finally, it would be easier to test potential solutions if your `File1` extract were larger (at least including the pattern that should be matched to `Queen_jerry`).

Comment: I've tried to make it clearer, thank you @steeldriver!

Comment: That's much clearer - thanks. So the entries from File2 should just be appended, in order, to the lines of File1 beginning with `>`?

Comment: That's right! I've tried variations of paste and awk but no success so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the lines of `File2` into an indexed awk array, and then append them in turn to the corresponding lines of `File`

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[i++]=$0; next} 
  /^>/ {$0 = $0" "a[j++];}
  {print}
  ' File2 File1
```

Alternatively, if you have GNU sed (with the `R` extension) you could try

```
sed '/^>/ R File2' File1 | sed '/^>/ {N;s/\n/ /}'
```

If your `File1` has exactly one additional line for every line that is to be matched, another option might be to double space `File2` and then `paste` the files together

```
sed 'G' File2 | paste -d ' ' File1 -
```

although that will result in an additional trailing space in the non-matching lines; if that's undesirable, you could insert a space at the start of each `File2` line and `paste` them without a delimiter

```
sed 's/^/ /; G' File2 | paste -d '' File1 -
```

Comment: Oh my gosh it worked it worked!!!! I cannot thank you enough!