# Combine multiple CSV files with Same Header into multiple group files

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, python, csv

Hi I am looking for a fastest solution to process loads of csv files.

*Situation:*
**I have multiple csv files in a single folder with *different* headers**

I have already done pre-processing on them to remove garbage lines on top so all has a *Standard Header*.

I would like to *MERGE GROUP OF CSV FILES* with *EXACT SAME HEARERS* to a *New folder*

```
Single Folder:
    Tree 
    ├── 161598827330618_data_aa.csv 
    ├── ..............  
    ├── ............... 
    ├── ................ 
    ├── 161598852706227_data_bh.csv 
Note: Filenames are Random with no pattern*
```

Sample File-1.csv

```
School Name,Project Description,Construction Award,Project type,Building ID,Building Address,City,Postcode
George HS - QUEENS,New,76850000,CAP,Q298,50-51 98TH STREET,Queens,11368 
MARBLE HILL INTERNATIONAL HS -,EXT MASONRY/FLOOD/PARAPETS/ROOFS,10490000,CIP,X475,99 TERRACE VIEW AVENUE,Bronx,10463
NEW DORP HS - STATEN ISLAND,PARTIAL ACCESSIBILITY,488000,CIP,R435,465 NEW DORP LANE,Staten Island,10306
```

Sample File-2.csv

```
School Name,Project Description,Construction Award,Project type,Building ID,Building Address,City,Postcode
EAST SIDE COMMUNITY SCHOOL,FIFTH FLOOR CEILING REPLACEMENT,150000,CIP,M060,420 EAST 12 STREET,Manhattan,10009
RICHMOND HILL HS - QUEENS,STEEL DETERIORATED COLUMS & COLUMN,1064400,CIP,Q475,89-30 114 STREET,Queens,11418
SUCCESS ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL,INTERIOR STAIRS,2045000,CIP,M099,410 EAST 100 STREET,Manhattan,10029
```

Sample File-3.csv

```
Reporting Period,Project Number,City,County,Zip Code,Sector,Solicitation,Electric Utility
02/28/2021,2453,Youngstown,,14174,Non-Residential,ARRA Projects,National Grid
02/28/2021,218852,Queens,Queens,11356,Residential,PON 2112,Consolidated Edison
02/28/2021,220037,Warwick,Orange,10990,Residential,PON 2112,Orange and Rockland Utilities
02/28/2021,2011-230103-SLPR,Center Moriches,Suffolk,11934,Residential,Solar ARRA Funding,Long Island Power Authority
```

Sample File-4.csv

```
Reporting Period,Project Number,City,County,Zip Code,Sector,Solicitation,Electric Utility
02/28/2021,2453,Youngstown,,14174,Non-Residential,ARRA Projects,National Grid
02/28/2021,218852,Queens,Queens,11356,Residential,PON 2112,Consolidated Edison
02/28/2021,220037,Warwick,Orange,10990,Residential,PON 2112,Orange and Rockland Utilities
02/28/2021,2011-230103-SLPR,Center Moriches,Suffolk,11934,Residential,Solar ARRA Funding,Long Island Power Authority
```

Sample File-5.csv

```
OBJECTID,Borough,PSSite,ParkName,ParkZone,PSStatus,GlobalID,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate
283721,Brooklyn,Street,,,Populated,C90AAD08-D99E-4759-A64C-219D6143BFB3,07-08-15 13:10,12/20/2019 04:34:58 PM
7669836,Queens,Park,Astoria Park,Q004-ZN02,Empty,AB55A658-8276-4734-A698-5FFCAE96578E,08/13/2020 01:18:00 PM,08/20/2020 06:15:32 PM
7123408,Brooklyn,Park,Asser Levy Park,,Populated,B32D93C9-5958-4129-A87A-FA7C9A5A4E87,01-09-20 13:15,01-09-20 13:17
```

Sample File-6.csv

```
OBJECTID,Borough,PSSite,ParkName,ParkZone,PSStatus,GlobalID,CreatedDate,UpdatedDate
6036681,Manhattan,Park,Riverside Park,,Populated,6A3E747D-CD5E-43EB-9789-67DB2064E878,04-11-18 11:11,08-06-20 21:21
7170578,Bronx,Park,Garden Of Eden,,Populated,B1E8B660-4B65-437F-B61F-06B1B71A4E1C,01/28/2020 03:18:00 PM,01/28/2020 03:19:26 PM
740416,Bronx,Park,Mullaly Park,X034-ZN02,Populated,E8F51E3B-CC6F-46A3-AF17-02B6BE8DCC57,08/26/2015 04:34:00 PM,01/30/2020 04:10:41 PM
5004669,Queens,Street,,,Populated,20157769-88EC-4867-9F50-852EF4814BF0,11-02-16 16:56,08-03-20 13:12:00 AM
```

Sample File-7.csv

```
Indicator,Group,State,Subgroup,Phase,Time Period,Time Period Label,Value,Low CI,High CI,Confidence Interval
Private Health Insurance Coverage,National Estimate,United States,United States,1,1,Apr 23 - May 5,75.4,74.7,76.2,74.7 - 76.2
Public Health Insurance Coverage,By Age,United States,18 - 24 years,1,1,Apr 23 - May 5,19.5,15.4,24.3,15.4 - 24.3
Uninsured at the Time of Interview,By Gender,United States,Female,1,1,Apr 23 - May 5,11,10.3,11.7,10.3 - 11.7
```

Sample File-8.csv

```
Year, dtmSurveyDate, ColonyID, strAOUCode, Type, strPhotoInterpreters, strColonyName, strCounty, strState, strCountry
2014,03-Jun-14,219-001,COMU,Image Check - No Birds,Kirsten Bixler,"""Tillamook Head Rocks"" (Eastern Rocks)",Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
2014,03-Jun-14,219-002,COMU,Image Check - No Birds,Kirsten Bixler,"""Tillamook Head Rocks"" (Northern Rock)",Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
2014,03-Jun-14,219-003,COMU,Shapefile-RawCount,Kirsten Bixler,"""Tillamook Head Rocks"" (Southwestern Rocks)",Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
2014,03-Jun-14,219-005,COMU,Shapefile,Shawn W. Stephensen,Tillamook Rock,Clatsop County,Oregon,United States
```

**Desired Result:**

Sample File-1.csv } 
Sample File-2.csv } Header check > `Same Header found`> MERGE  > `GROUP-1.csv`

Sample File-3.csv } 
Sample File-4.csv } Header check > `Same Header found`> MERGER > `GROUP-2.csv`

Sample File-5.csv }
Sample File-6.csv } Header check > `Same Header found` > MERGER > `GROUP-3.csv`

Sample File-7.csv } Header check > `No Similar Headers`  > NOTHING> `GROUP-5.csv`
Sample File-8.csv } Header check > `No Similar Headers`  > NOTHING> `GROUP-6.csv`

Preferable Solution: Bash Script and Linux Commands
Solutions Tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
  FNR==1{
    if (!($0 in h)||file!=h[$0]){close(file)}
    if (!($0 in h)){file=h[$0]=i++}
    else{file=h[$0];next}
  }
  {print >> (file)}
' ./*.csv
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602291/459978
The above method work but I am not sure if it can handle 1000s of files for processing and categorizing.
I need Group*.csv formats to be created in an different folder.

Shortest Time of Completion is important
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921621/3088275

**Looking for an Op code with Awk or Sed or Linux commands for bash script which ever is fastest to achieve the desired output**

Comment: If the solution fromthe referenced question works, why don't you simply try if it works with a large amount of data and fulfils your time requirements? If you want to create the output in a different folder, `cd` to the output folder and specify the input files like `../input/*.csv` or `/path/to/input/*.csv`

Comment: want an improvement of the Op code or new code with speed improvisation which is reliable for realtime

Comment: Your answer doesn't make your requirements clear. Please explain **in your question** why you think that you need speed improvement when you apparently did not even check if the existing code runs too slow. Please explain what exactly you mean with "reliable for realtime". You can [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: @Bodo Requirement is mentioned clearly in 'Desired output' Heading, the code creates empty files with no extension, i really dont understand the exact functioning of code and hence need an explanation, alternative code preferable which is human readable/understandable, as per the speed looking for benchmarks like this -https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921621/3088275, if you can improvise the code let me know

Comment: Then **please [edit] your question** and show or explain the actual output you get and the expected output you want instead. I also suggest to remove everything related to speed because it distracts from your real problem. If you later find out that the script might run too slow then write a separate question where you clearly state your speed requirements.

Comment: Ignore the speed and improvise theOp - `alternative code preferable which is human readable/understandable`

Comment: See [ask] and [tour] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I could improve the code for sure, and I cound also help if you would tell what you don't understand in the explanation that is present in the linked answer. But as you choose to ignore my comments and refuse to improve the question I will choose to not answer it.

Comment: I'm sorry but that code seems very clear and understandable. So since you don't explain what your issues with it are, we can't really help. That solution is also likely to be very, very fast. So on the whole it seems like you don't need anything from us. You already have what looks like a very fast and efficient solution that does what you need.

Comment: @terdon Explain the code in that case if the code cannot be refactored, presently it provides only empty file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is it guaranteed that the duplicate headers are found only in consecutive files?  With this answer I wanted to handle if that is not the case:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare header_list[] to be an associative array
declare -A header_list

# Read the first line from every *.csv file in $1
# Each filename is added to the appropriate entry in header_list[]
for f in "${1:?}"/*.csv; do
  echo "### Reading header from $f"
  header_list[$(head -1 "$f")]+="${IFS}$f"
done

# Handle the list of files for each entry in header_list[]
group_id=1
for key in "${!header_list[@]}"; do
  value="${header_list[$key]}"
  groupfile="${2:?}/GROUP-${group_id}.csv"
  echo "### Header: ${key}"
  echo "### Group File: ${groupfile}"
  
  # Echo the header as the first line of $groupfile
  echo "${key}" > "${groupfile}"
  
  # Skip the first line, but echo every other line from each file with this header
  for file in ${value}; do
  echo "# File: ${file}"
    tail --lines=+2 "$file" >> "${groupfile}"
  done
  
  # Increment group_id
  (( group_id++ ))
done
```

Save to a file and then run with two arguments: The directory containing the source files, and the output directory.

Some caveats:

- The output directory must exist.
- Filenames with characters in $IFS will not be handled properly.