# Concatenate files with same structure, keeping header only for 1st file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ksh

I want to merge 28 files with different names and the same data structure, using the script below:

```
$ cp mohan.csv Consolidate.csv
$ for fname in line
    do 
      cat $fname | sed '1d' >> Consolidate.csv
    done < input.txt
```

while `input.txt` contains:

```
mohan.csv
babu.csv
mahesh.csv
datvik.csk
... etc
```

and

```
$ cat mohan.csv
no,name,dept
1,xyz,hr
2,abc,sales
```

Output of my script:

```
$ cat Consolidate.csv
no,name,dept
1,xyz,hr
2,abc,sales
babu.csv
mahesh.csv
datvik.csk
... etc
```

Please, help me with this.

Comment: You read each input line into `line`, but use `$fname` in the loop?

Comment: while is working fine. for loop is not working with the above script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate multiple files with same header](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60577/concatenate-multiple-files-with-same-header)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of tools for this job. I assume that you want to keep the first header and get rid of the other ones. So it is just a matter of appending to the untouched first file, while getting rid of headers in other files.

Get rid of `mohan.csv` in `input.txt`:

```
$ cat input.txt
babu.csv
mahesh.csv
datvik.csk
... etc
```

Then:

```
$ cp mohan.csv consolidate.csv
$ for file in "$(<input.txt)"; do
    sed '/no,name,dept/d' "$file" >> consolidate.csv
  done
```

Or with `read`:

```
$ cp mohan.csv consolidate.csv
$ while read -r file; do
    sed '/no,name,dept/d' "$file" >> consolidate.csv
  done <  input.txt
```

Or, much simpler still, a pure `sed` answer found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204343/72707

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the list of files is potentially longer than what could be handled by a single invocation of some external command (so the filenames in `input.txt` can't be listed on the command line in one go).

Assuming that the list of positional parameters (i.e., the list of arguments to some script) contains the list of pathnames of files that we'd like to concatenate, and that we'd like to take the header from only the first of these if the output file does not already exist.  If the output file already exists, we can assume that the header already was written to the output.

The minimal code for doing this in the shell would be something like

```bash
[ ! -e outfile ] && head -n 1 -- "$1" >outfile
awk 'FNR != 1' "$@" >>outfile
```

Here, `head -n 1` is used to get only the header from the very first file and write it to `outfile`, if the file `outfile` does not already exist.  Then, `awk` is used to extract all but the first line from all files, appending these lines to `outfile`.

This tiny script could be executed with all the input files from your `input.txt` file, assuming the filenames in `input.txt` are properly quoted or otherwise "simple" (no embedded whitespace characters, or quotes):

```bash
xargs sh -c '
    out=$1; shift
    [ ! -e "$out" ] && head -n 1 -- "$1" >"$out"
    awk "FNR != 1" "$@" >>"$out"
' sh Consolidate.csv <input.txt
```

This uses `xargs` to run a small in-line `sh -c` script, taking the input from `input.txt` as arguments.  The output filename, `Consolidate.csv`, is given as the first argument and received into `out` in the in-line script.

If the list in `input.txt` is very long, `xargs` will arrange for our in-line script to be called several times, with batches of arguments read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
awk 'NR==1 || FNR > 1' $(< input.txt )
```

Don't quote the "command substitution" so it produces a list of file names on `awk`'s command line (up to the LINE_MAX system config parameter). Should your file names contain white space characters, revert to an array:

```
readarray -t Arr < input.txt
awk 'NR==1 || FNR > 1' "${Arr[@]}"
```

Should your header span more than one line, adapt the two numbers-to-be-compared in the `awk` script.